Animated series that tells stories based on fairy tales by Grimm Brothers, Hans Christian Andersen and others
When I was a kid I think it was around early 2000s, a local TV channel aired a cartoon which oddly got stuck in my mind for only few parts of it. 
As I remember, it probably tells stories based on fairy tales by Grimm Brothers, Hans Christian Andersen and others. 
What really disturb me is, the only part I vividly remember was the credit (either it was opening or ending, I do not remember unfortunately). The credit showed an attic where a sparkling sunlight came in through a window. 
The floor was made from wood, so as the window. Maybe before the attic part, it showed woods with wild flowers but I'm not sure about this part. 
The next thing I remember the most is that the credit played Habanera of Georges Bizet or at least any other classical music but my memory plays Habanera alongside with the attic view.
I do not know when it was released, and it was colored. As I remember it was dubbed by the language of my country (Indonesia). I cannot identify the country origin, since I can only remember very little about it. but it was probably from US or Europe.
It disturbs me since I cannot recall the rest of the cartoon while my memory keep playing the attic part over and over again. I searched through Google but I found nothing. 
At first I thought my memory was trying to remind me about Simsala Grimm from Germany but as I saw the opening and ending credit, there was no attic with window full of sparkling sunlight moreover the Habanera song.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released, we don't know when you were a kid? Was it in Color or Black & White?  What country was it likely from or what language was it in?  Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

"Simsala Grimm" Actually, there is an attic, an open window and shimmering light in the show's intro (see here). As for the song, perhaps it only appeared in certain dubs?
